# a hard query to write in mysql to me?

Tags: php, mysql

```
field:   content_id, value=1 or  value=0, value_type=option
table:  votingapi_vote
```

1,output the content_id field and descending it, the rule is according to the value(the count of each content_id 's value=1  minus the count of each content_id 's value=0 ,each content_id has many value=0 or value=1). where `the value_type=option`

is there a way to get that?

namely:

```
$query1=mysql_query(SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE value_type = option  AND value = 1 GROUP BY content_id)

$query2=mysql_query(SELECT content_id, COUNT(*) FROM votingapi_vote WHERE value_type = option  AND value = 0 GROUP BY content_id)
```

i want to use the count value = 1 minus the count value = 0. this is the content_id's descending rule,

For each content_id, the number of rows with value=1 minus the number of rows with value=0

Comment: how to write the question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Comment: I think my brain just popped!

Comment: For each content_id, the number of rows with value=1 minus the number of rows with value=0? Is that right?

Comment: yes! yes!..you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT content_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 
                WHEN value=0 THEN -1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS ContentSum
    FROM votingapi_vote
    WHERE value_type = 'option'
    GROUP BY content_id
    ORDER BY ContentSum DESC
```

Comment: Instead of the CASE statement:  SUM(2 * value - 1)

Comment: @Mark: Sure that would work. Personally, I prefer the `CASE` because 1) it more explicitly defines the rules that were given (makes it easier on the next person who has to look at the code) and 2) it will properly handle any unexpected rogue data (e.g., value=3).

Comment: Joe Stefanelli,you're my hero. you answer work like a charm. many many thanks. but i don't know what's CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 
                WHEN value=0 THEN -1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) meaning.

Comment: and why can use 2 * value - 1 in place of it?

Comment: @zhuanzhou: The SUM/CASE defines your conditions. IF value=1 we add 1 to the sum, IF value = 0 we add -1 (same as subtracting +1) ELSE we add 0 (do nothing). `2*value-1` would work because `2*1-1 = 1` and `2*0-1 = -1`

Comment: IF value=1 we add 1 to the sum, IF value = 0 we add -1 . could i  IF value=1 we add 2 to the sum, IF value = 0 we add 1? thank you.

Comment: @zhuanzhou: Just change the numbers on the `THEN` portions of the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT content_id, SUM(CASE value WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) valuesum
FROM votingapi_vote
WHERE value_type = 'option'
GROUP BY content_id
ORDER BY valuesum DESC
```

Comment: I missed that part of your question - I'm sorry, I struggled to understand what you had written!