# left join or right join in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

```
table1: node
fields: nid, ,title,type,created
```

query1:

```
mysql_query(SELECT nid,title, type,created FROM `node` where type="provider"  ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0 , 22)



table2:  votingapi_vote
fields:   content_id, value=1 or  value=0, value_type=option
```

query2:

```
SELECT content_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 
                WHEN value=0 THEN -1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS ContentSum
    FROM votingapi_vote
    WHERE value_type = 'option'
    GROUP BY content_id
    ORDER BY ContentSum DESC
```

`content_id` value equals `nid` value, but in table 1, the `nid` maybe not has the  one - to - one correspondence to the table 2.  eg:

```
table 1     table2
nid          content_id

1              1
2              3
3
```

but the `content_id` has  one - to - one correspondence to the `nid` in table 1.

now, i want to get a `title list`. which unmber is `22`. the `descending order` is according to `ContentSum`  and `created`. is there a way to get this? should i use `left join`? i don't know how to make the two query  turn into one?

[a hard query to write in mysql to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072631/a-hard-query-to-write-in-mysql-to-me/6072698)

**rephrase it**:

table one structure {node}:

```
nid        type             title                 created

10          provider        test one              1298107010
11          provider        test two              1298107555    
12          provider        example one            1300524695 
13          provider        example two            1298081391
14          provider        example three          1298082340
15          company         example four           1298083519
16....      company         example five          1298083559
```

table two structure {votingapi_vote}:

```
content_id      value    value_type

10                1          option
10                 0          option
11                 1          option
12                 0          option
15                 3          percent
15                 2          percent
16.....            0          option
```

i want:

get 22 titles list

```
...
test one
test two
example one
example two 
...
```

1, the value of `nid` is equals the value of `content_id` in table 2.

**the title list queue order is**:

1, first according to table 2  `content_id` descending the tile list(decending  content_id using "For each content_id, the number of rows with value=1 minus the number of rows with value=0" )

2, because table2 maybe less than 22 records  and has the same value when the number of rows with value=1 minus the number of rows with value=0. when emerge this condition. using the `created` field in table 1 to descending the `tile`

Comment: If you could rephrase the question to make it easier to read and to see exactly what is required that would be great.

Comment: i am sorry, the question is too hard to describe.namely. i want to get a title list. which unmber is 22. the descending order is according to table2 ContentSum and and table1 created.

Comment: I agree with Will. Provide DDL of the two tables, example data, and expected output of the query.

Comment: i have updated the question. expect it more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example you've provided some of it is not clear to me. I'll just give a query that combining the two query you've provided.

Try this

```
SELECT nid,title, type,created, v_api.ContentSum
  FROM `node` n
  LEFT JOIN ( SELECT content_id,
                     SUM(CASE WHEN value=1 THEN 1 
                         WHEN value=0 THEN -1 
                         ELSE 0 
                     END) AS ContentSum
                FROM votingapi_vote
               WHERE value_type = 'option'
               GROUP BY content_id) v_api 
    ON n.nid = v_api.content_id
 where type="provider"
ORDER BY v_api.ContentSum DESC, created DESC LIMIT 0 , 22;
```

Note: you can remove some of the columns that you don't need.

Other things to know:

- Using `LEFT JOIN` will also create a row that doesn't have an equivalent `nid to content_id`. That's the reason I added `v_api.ContentSum` for you to see that it will create a `null` value.
- You can use `COALESCE` if you want to add a value if it's return `null`. You can use `INNER JOIN` If you don't want to include the row that have a `v_api.ContentSum` equal to `null`.
- About `RIGHT JOIN` I'm not sure if this is what you need with regards to your question base on my understanding.

Also take a look on this [mysql/join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

I hope this can be a help.

Comment: i am sorry, it output nothing. when i delete the left join. it can output something. thank you

Comment: Sure? check if the column fields is correct. I did a test in my work-bench before I post it and I get a results. Where did you test it?

Comment: you are my hero! very happy. you  helped me solve a hard question. but i don't know what's the real meaning of your query.

Comment: The tricky part here is the `LEFT JOIN`, it just a create a `virtual table` using a sub query. And use that `v_table` like a table. I just use `virtual table` because I don't know how to call it :)

Comment: aha.i don't know why Using LEFT JOIN will also create a row that doesn't have an equivalent nid to content_id.

Comment: It is because it will return all rows in the `left table` which is `node` even it doesn't have a matches on the `right table` which is votingapi_vote. It is better to read some documents about join, see the link I've provided.

Answer (score 5):

```
<table1> left join <table2>
```

Means that tuples do not have to have a matching element in table2 but all elements in table1 will be included.

```
<table1> right join <table2>
```

Means that tuples do not have to have a matching element in table1 but all elements in table2 will be included.

Comment: thank you. but i don't know how to write the query. it's too complicated.

Comment: Great concise explanation of difference between left & right join.